# How do I prevent Ajax calls from keeping a session alive?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using cookie authentication in [`MVC5`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started).  My web pages rely heavily on authenticated as well as unauthenticated Ajax calls every 1-5 seconds to keep data updated. Consequently, my users never log out of the site.

My ideal scenario: If a user is actively browsing or conducting actions on my site, keep the session alive. If they have left a page open after 10 minutes, I'd like their session to timeout and I’'ll use the failing Ajax calls to redirect to a login page. I think this would best be accomplished at the controller or action level.

I tried controlling the session state behavior as suggested below but the session still did not time out.  After 65 seconds of hitting ReadOnly/Public once per second, I call ReadOnly/Authorized and successfully retrieve data from it.

Here is my CookieAuthentication configuration.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
    });
}
```

My test page:

```
<div id="public"></div>
<div id="authorized"></div>


@section scripts{
<script>

function poll(times) {
    var url = '/ReadOnly/Public';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: null,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#public').html(times + ' ' + data.test);

        },
        error: function (data) {
            $('#public').html(times + ' ' + 'failed');
        }
    });
};

function checkAuth(times) {
    var url = '/ReadOnly/Authorized';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: null,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#authorized').html(times + ' ' + data.test);

        },
        error: function (data) {
            $('#authorized').html(times + ' ' + 'failed');
        }
    });
};

$(function () {
    var times = 1;
    setInterval(function () {
        poll(times);
        times++;
    }, 1000);
    setInterval(function () {
        checkAuth(times);
    }, 65000);

});
</script>
}
```

and test controller code (tried this with both the disabled and readonly options)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace SessionTest.Controllers
{
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class ReadOnlyController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Authorized()
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            test = "ReadOnly and Authorized"
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public ActionResult Public()
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            test = "ReadOnly and Public"
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: how does the current implementation behave? is it logging out in 10 mins regardless of what user does or failing to logout 10 mins after user becomes idle?

Comment: The user never logs out.  Their session is open indefinitely because the Ajax calls are made every 5 seconds and the timeout window is 10 minutes.

Comment: why do you want to do this ? If they navigate away from webpage, or manually log out (I assume that option is still there) the session will die. If not it remains, that all sounds fine. I hate timeouts, they are a pain.

Comment: From a user experience perspective, think of a financial app.  You want to enforce a timeout so that the user doesn't leave their desk then get their money siphoned away.  From a server resourcing perspective, I want to preserve the network and database load if the user isn't active.

Comment: I follow the rule, Help those who are willing to help themselves. You have an infinite loop to an authorized controller, are unwilling to implement a sessionstate, and are clearly unwilling to write your own cookie provider. You ask for a miracle and are un-willing to work with anyone on your needs. I delete my answer and wish you the best of luck.

Comment: @NimChimpsky One other factor I'd prefer server control of the session is that there is a security issue with MVC5 where even if you call the logout action in the accounts controller, it doesn't actually invalidate the session.  You're vulnerable to session hijacking.  We use ssl to minimize the attack vector but there are concern like shared public computers, etc.

Comment: @BillShihara manually invalidate the session, as i state in my answer

Comment: @NimChimpsky how do you manually invalidate the session on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need to have 2 separate web apps. One is for serving authenticated requests. Another one is for all public requests.

That's similar to how the Google Analytics script creates and maintains its own Session on Google side about your site without impacting your web application's internal session management. Otherwise, you will get stuck with the default behavior of ASP .NET the way it is handling cookies and keeps session alive.

Good luck.

Comment: After a lot of experimentation and hair pulling, I think this is the solution we're going to move towards.  Thanks to everyone who listened to my frustrating set of business requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't implement a timeout in this situation. In fact I try to avoid them unless there is a fundamental and key reason why they are necessary, otherwise they just become an annoyance.

However if you do feel you need one, I would implement it in this case, by creating a separate javascript function which has a timer, and that is reset with user input. If the timer completes an ajax call is performed that executes a manual session invalidation on server side.

Answer (score 2):

I would configure the listener method or class to not use session which will prevent it from being extended.

There are attributes available for both methods and controllers that provides different session modes.

More info here: 
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/906b060113-Controlling-Session-Behavior-in-Asp.Net-MVC4.html

Comment: I just tested this and the session doesn't time out.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax calls will keep the session alive.

One approach will be to set a timeout on client side to delete cookie after some time.
I'm not sure you have anymore options.

If the calls every 5 sec are only to non-authenticated request, just keep the cookie out of the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sliding expiration is set to true by default.

I think perhaps when the call that is made to the action Public, it's made with cookie and thus extending the timeout.

```
    public ActionResult Public()
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            test = "ReadOnly and Public"
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

If I set this below: (SlidingExpiration = false). I get the failed message.

```
       app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            ExpireTimeSpan =  TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0),
            SlidingExpiration = false
            //Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            //{
            //    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            //        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            //        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            //}
        });
```

Comment: I did check this and my sample code has the cache flag set.

Comment: Do you have a setting in your web.config to remove the     <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />

Comment: If so, I think there is a typo it should be FormsAuthentication not FormsAuthenticationModule.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither       <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />  or        <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" /> solved the problem.  The session still did not time out.