# Prevent session timeout from resetting for periodical AJAX calls (.NET Framework 4)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC application (.NET Framework 4.6.1) there is a periodical AJAX call to fetch new notifications for the user. However this call resets the idle timeout for the current session, causing the session to never expire.

How can I prevent certain endpoint calls from resetting the idle timeout?

I found [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67020561/prevent-session-timeout-from-resetting-for-periodical-ajax-calls) but the code seems to be for .NET Core.

Comment: Does this answer it?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459228/how-do-i-prevent-ajax-calls-from-keeping-a-session-alive

Comment: No - or at least I could not find some information that could help me in this thread.